# ConnectionID in HSQL

Tags: hsqldb

I'm looking for the id of the connection in hsqldb.

In oracle I use : `SELECT Userenv('SESSIONID') from DUAL`

In MySql I use : `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()`

In HSQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HSQLDB 2.x, session is the same as the connection. You can use:

```
CALL SESSION_ID()
```

When Oracle syntax compatibility mode is used, you can also use:

```
SELECT SESSION_ID() FROM DUAL
```

And in MySql syntax compatibility mode:

```
SELECT SESSION_ID()
```

See the list of related functions here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#builtin_functions_sysfunc-sect